# Is there a wireless alternative of a Plumb Bob?

Tags: civil-engineering, instrumentation, construction-management

A [Plumb Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plumb_bob) is an elegant and technically very simple device for maintaining vertical alignment of components at different heights during construction. Yet in practice its application in large-scale constructions is very limited, I believe. The biggest shortcoming that comes to mind is the need for a free passage of the thread between the parts to be aligned, which is difficult to do over large distances in the middle of an ongoing construction work.

Is there a more high-tech wireless device that is used by the construction industry nowadays for vertical alignment of construction blocks?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the laser level.

Some have lenses to do points of light, sheets etc so floors can be checked for level by showing high points etc

One I borrowed allowed me to put a line across the floor, ceiling and both walls. All inline and vertical.

Comment: "*need for a free passage of the thread*" kind of eliminates anything I can think of.

Comment: "*The biggest shortcoming that comes to mind is the need for a free passage of the thread between the parts to be aligned ...*" If there isn't passage for a thread then there may not be for light either. I read the question as thinking of a radio solution.

Comment: @Transistor or was it simply that the thread sags due to its own mass?

Comment: "*A Plumb Bob ... for maintaining **vertical** alignment ...*" Sagging not a problem.

Comment: @Transistor "at different heights" which I thought light can achieve - does not get moved by wind etc And radio signals propagate so you pkanning radar or something?

Comment: I'm not planning anything! I have no solution to the question.

Comment: I think OP does want something like a radio laser. Or a magic device that knows it's location and alignment relative to another device.

Comment: Thread is not an issue for the laser as long as you can handle occasional interruptions.